# How to delete the odd attributes while rendering form

Tags: widget, twig, symfony

I rewrite some widgets in `bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig` and I don't want the form fields to have some attributes while they are rendered.

I've found out the sequence of some widgets
`button_widget` → `button_row` → `form_widget` → `widget_attributes`

And I made a little change

```
{% block widget_attributes %}
    {% spaceless %}
    {# bla-bla-bla #}
        {% for attrname, attrvalue in attr %}
            {% if attrname in ['placeholder', 'title'] %}
                {{ attrname }}="{{ attrvalue|trans({}, translation_domain) }}"
            {% elseif attrname not in ['first','last','data-help'] %}
                {{ attrname }}="{{ attrvalue }}"
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock widget_attributes %}
```

But it doesn't work for buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<del>It's strange, but the form layout in twig_bridge has some widgets to work with attributes.</del>

<del>1. for inputs `widget_attributes`
 2. for buttons `button_attributes`
 3. for another element `widget_container_attributes`</del>

For each widget, there are next blocks in twig-bridge:

1. `{name_of_widget}_widget` - main block to render an element
2. `{name_of_widget}_label`
3. `{name_of_widget}_row`

And for attributes, there are

1. `widget_attributes`
2. `widget_container_attributes`
3. `button_attributes`
4. `attributes`

I just used incorrect one :)
Thank all for your patience.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are achieving but you can intercept the odd index of a twig loop as follow:

```
{% for attrname, attrvalue in attr %}
      {% if loop.index is odd %}
          odd 
      {% else %}
          even
      {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

More info on [loop variable](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable) and [odd test function](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tests/odd.html#odd).

Hope this help

Comment: I don't know what index that attribute will have.
And, my algorithm works with the input fields.